# Changing .net languagepack on Swedish Windows 7 home premium

Tags: .net-framework

Im running Windows 7 Home Premium Swedish but im trying to get .net 2.0 to display in English
Google tells me to uninstall the languagepack for .net but there isn't one avaliable
since it seems that .net 2.0 is a OS component on Windows 7.

I've tried uninstalling .net with the removal tool but 2.0 is never actually removed
So I can't install the english distributionalpack

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to install the English language pack for the whole Windows 7.It should be available as optional update in Windows Update. Not sure if this applies to Home Premium too (works in Ultimate).

This because .NET threads set their language according to the configured OS language by default. Exceptions, alerts, etc. use that language to display their messages